# Session between vbScript and jScripr

Tags: asp-classic

My website is coded using `vbscript` in which session variables are created but suddenly I use one `jscript` page. It seems that the session id change at that moment.

How can I conserve it?

Thanks!

Edit : see my next message for more precisions.

---

I have an idea. My jscript page call another asp page using an xmlhttp object and this is the called page that complaints about the error. I think this is because the request to the asp page in question is made server-side. Thus, the page receive the session id of the server, not from the client. How can I change that in your opinion ?

Comment: It should work just fine and got nothing to do with VBScript/JScript difference.

Answer (score 0):

could very well not be the problem in your case but some weeks ago I had a problem with session id changing, in my case it was caused by an underscore in the site name. This is a weird IIS bug

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you pre cise

Comment: Thank you. There is no underscore in my url.

Comment: @Gaby: by site name do you mean the host name that the site is bound to?

Comment: The problem was the site name. As it is shown in IIS under sites. The host name and full url did not contain any underscores.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an underscore in the session name try removing that.

We had a similar issue recently. I'm not sure of the exact reason (perhaps encoding of names), but removing the underscore sorted it out.